# (jquery, laravel, html) code change from multiple select to checkbox select

Tags: php, jquery, html, laravel, checkbox

I want to change from multiple select to checkbox select.

original code is this.

```
<form action="{{ route('video.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form__article">
{!! csrf_field() !!}

<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('tags') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="tags">{{ trans('forum.articles.form_tags') }}</label>
  <select name="tags[]" id="tags" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" >
    @foreach($allTags as $tag)
      <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">
        {{ $tag->name }}
      </option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
  {!! $errors->first('tags', '<span class="form-error">:Error message</span>') !!}
</div>

....

</form>
```

I tried this code, but don't work. form-error(Error message) occured.
I think the type of result is different...

```
<form action="{{ route('video.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form__article">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('tags') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="tags">{{ trans('forum.articles.form_tags') }}</label>
  <div name="tags[]" id="tags" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" >
      @foreach($allTags as $tag)
      <input type="Checkbox" name="{{ $tag->name }}" value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}
      @endforeach
  {!! $errors->first('tags', '<span class="form-error">:Error message</span>') !!}
  </div>
</div>

....

</form>
```

(additon)

I tried this, but "PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'ex_tag1' for column 'tag_id' at row 1" occured...

```
<div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('tags') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
  <label for="tags">{{ trans('forum.articles.form_tags') }}</label><br>

      @foreach($allTags as $tag)
      <input type="Checkbox" name="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]" value="{{ $tag->name }}">{{ $tag->name }}
      @endforeach
  {!! $errors->first('tags', '<span class="form-error">:message</span>') !!}
  </div>
```

I need your advise.
thank you.

Comment: get rid of the `<div name="tags[]" id="tags" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" >` and change `name="{{ $tag->name }}" ` to `name="tags[{{ $tag->id }}]" value="{{ $tag->name }}"`

Comment: // Lawrence Cherone - sorry, "ErrorException Undefined variable: tag" occured.

Comment: looks like the variable `$tag` is undefined ;p, can you update your snippets with the code you have changed.

Comment: NO, in your question!!!!

Comment: sorry. my mistake.but  " SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'ex_tag' for column 'tag_id' at row 1" occured.